# PHP, Wordpress die(); problems

Tags: php, wordpress, exit, die

Having an odd problem.
I have a plugin that I'm using that is a login register page that uses `die();`
when it runs normally it just kills the page after login and redirects showing the user is now logged in but returns to same page where it logins into. What I want is to redirect to the homepage after `die();` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code (Exemple 1):

```
else {
                echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting now')));
            }
            die();
```

The code that I thought would work is this (Exemple 2):

```
 else {
                echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting now')));
            }
            wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/some/page' )
            die();
```

However putting anything before `die` causes the page to just do nothing. It shows a gif saying it's thinking but never reloads never refreshes page never redirects. If I force it to reload the page it just says im logged in
and returns me to the login page, but not the home page or anything I set in example 2.

Any ideas?

PS: I've tried `exit();` with the same described results.

Comment: Looks like this is for a JSON resource, most probably for AJAX requests. You're meant to handle the response client side

Comment: thanks phil. for your reply. i just found a solution to the issue. :)

Comment: You have a missing semicolon after `wp_redirect()`

Answer (score 0):

turns out i figured it out myself.

```
            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
               echo "<script>location.href='http://www.example.com';</script>";
               die();

        }
```

Comment: I cannot fathom how this works with the code in your question.